# Error in as.igraph.Node

Tags: r, graph

I have a Newick tree (t1):

```
> t1
                    levelName
    1 {Petal.Width           
    2  °--Petal.Width        
    3      °--Petal.Length   
    4          °--Petal.Width

> class (t1)
    [1] "Node" "R6"
```

When I use  as.igraph.Node I get the following error:

```
> ig <- as.igraph.Node(t1, "p", c("level", "isLeaf"))
Error in as.igraph.Node(t1, "p", c("level", "isLeaf")) : 
  Node names must be unique withing the tree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stems from the repetition of the names in the nodes. `as.igraph.Node` does not support repetition of the same names in the nodes.